# Need advice executing awk commands resulting from output of Ansible ad-hoc command

Tags: awk, ansible

When I execute the following command to find index IDs by using an Ansible ad-hoc command:

```
$ ansible oamvip -i /storage/inventory/None/${myvnf}hosts --become -m shell -a "/usr/sbin/aladmin list | grep "PartitionUsage" | awk '{ print \$2 }'"
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
4818b4715eb6542838023
e520bec15eb6542838023
```

However, when I try to execute a shell command (`sh`) on the results from the `awk` output, Ansible shows me the help menu:

```
$ ansible oamvip -i /storage/inventory/None/${myvnf}hosts --become -m shell -a "/usr/sbin/aladmin list | grep "PartitionUsage" | awk '{ print "aladmin show " \$2 | "sh"}'"
Usage: ansible <host-pattern> [options]
```

I've tried single and double quotes, backslashes, to no avail.  Please advise.

Comment: Looks like your awk command is malformed. If I have to guess you need to escape the double quotes in the awk command. Also, I think you need a comma after the "aladmin show" `$ ansible oamvip -i /storage/inventory/None/${myvnf}hosts --become -m shell -a "/usr/sbin/aladmin list | grep "PartitionUsage" | awk '{ print \"aladmin show \", \$2 | \"sh\"}'" `

Comment: @ventsyv Without the comma `awk` just combines the arguments to `print`. With the comma they get separated by `OFS` (space).

Comment: @HaukeLaging My awk is very rusty...

Answer (score 1):

```
"/usr/sbin/aladmin list | grep "PartitionUsage" | awk '{ print \$2 }'"
```

is just one string (word) from the perspective of the shell which parses the whole command line. I assume it is passed to `sh -c`. Independent of your problem, it should be

```
"/usr/sbin/aladmin list | grep \"PartitionUsage\" | awk '{ print \$2 }'"
```

or

```
"/usr/sbin/aladmin list | grep PartitionUsage | awk '{ print \$2 }'"
```

instead.

```
set -x
: "/usr/sbin/aladmin list | grep "PartitionUsage" | awk '{ print "aladmin show " \$2 | "sh"}'"
+ : '/usr/sbin/aladmin list | grep PartitionUsage | awk '\''{ print aladmin' show ' $2 | sh}'\'''
```

Those are three words for the shell and thus for `ansible` which does not understand these arguments.

It's again the `"`.

```
awk '{ print "aladmin show " \$2 | "sh"}'
```

must become

```
awk '{ print \"aladmin show \" \$2 | \"sh\"}'
```

**BTW**

There is (nearly in general and especially in this case) no reason for a

```
... | grep ... | awk ...
```

pipeline as (with few exceptions like PCRE) `awk` can do everything that `grep` can.

```
grep PartitionUsage | awk '{ print \$2 }'
```

=>

```
awk '/PartitionUsage/ { print \$2 }'
```

Comment: Awesome Hauke, your solution worked perfectly!  Also got rid of 'grep'.

Comment: @Bjoern Then you should accept my answer so that your question does not look unanswered any more.

Comment: Sorry, had to change PCs, for some reason this page won't reload on my other PC.